# Using krivochenko/yii2-cropper to upload image doesn't work

Tags: php, image, yii2, crop

I don't know what's wrong with my code because i think, i have following all the step from github [krivochenko/yii2-cropper](https://github.com/krivochenko/yii2-cropper) But button to cropping or delete upload doesn't work and and also the css displayed on the form is not neat like this :

[image: capture]

i'm not see any error in console, and i want to include the code i made :

```
this is in view :

use budyaga\cropper\Widget;

<div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->widget(Widget::className(), [
      'uploadUrl' => Url::toRoute($uploadPhoto['url']),
      ]) ?>
</div>
```

then this is in controller:

```
return $this->render('input', [
      'model' => $model,
      'uploadPhoto' => [
            'class' => 'budyaga\cropper\actions\UploadAction',
            'url' => 'content/user/create',
            'path' => $this->baseApp.'/files/uploads',
        ]
    ]);
```

So what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i can understand what wrong with my code.

1. I need to adjust css from this widget in my own with add param in widget input form.:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->widget(Widget::className(), [
   'uploadUrl' => Url::toRoute($uploadPhoto['url']),
   'cropAreaHeight' => 'auto' //here
]) ?>
```

2. i put `Upload Photo` index into create action, `Upload Photo` should be placed in function action(general) like this:

```
public function actions()
  {
    return [
      'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
      ],
      'uploadPhoto' => [
          'class' => 'budyaga\cropper\actions\UploadAction',
          'url' => 'dir_to_save_the_result_of_crop',
          'path' => 'path_to_save_the_result_of_crop',
        ]
    ];
  }
```

And this widget [krivochenko/yii2-cropper](https://github.com/krivochenko/yii2-cropper) can works also really easy to use in yii2